# Does an Android configuration change happen mid-function? What about callbacks?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, callback

When a configuration change occurs, will that interrupt the currently executing function on the main thread? Or is the function guaranteed to complete before the configuration change occurs?

Similar question for callbacks to the main thread. If you have some AsyncTask that gets kicked off from some function on the main thread, is that function guaranteed to complete before the AsyncTask calls back and begins executing code on the main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a configuration change occurs on the main thread.  It won't occur in the middle of execution of one of those functions.

An AsyncTask is asynchronous.  It may not finish before the activity is recreated and will not be killed by a configuration change.  It will continue to execute, and if it calls UI view functions in onPostExecute that will cause an exception (because those views no longer exist).  You need to protect against that.  IMO its one of the reasons the ending and recreating of Activities on configuration change ranks in the top 5 stupidest design decisions in history.  I highly recommend turning that off if you have async tasks or threads going on.  It will simplify your code and prevent having to redo the AsyncTask or having problems in onPostExecute.

Comment: As a test, I tried putting a long sleep on the main thread (30 seconds) and found that it will still allow a config change (screen rotates) in the middle of the sleep. I found that kind of odd.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration change causes the activity to be destroyed and recreated with saved instance, if any.  But if there was any background thread spawned from activity's main thread, then it has an implicit reference of the activity and unless that background thread gets finished, the activity does not get GCd, but for sure another activity will be created. And if you keep changing the configuration will end up throwing OutOfMemoryException.

See this link for best way to handle configChanges and backgruond tasks:  http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

1.

> When a configuration change occurs, will that interrupt the currently
>   executing function on the main thread? Or is the function guaranteed
>   to complete before the configuration change occurs?

Answer:**The function is guaranteed to complete**

2.

> Similar question for callbacks to the main thread. If you have some
>   AsyncTask that gets kicked off from some function on the main thread,
>   is that function guaranteed to complete before the AsyncTask calls
>   back and begins executing code on the main thread?

Answer:**The function is independent of configuration change(that is why it is called async) i.e it is not guaranteed to complete before the configuration change occurs.**

Comment: For #2, the AsyncTask will invoke onPostExecute on the main thread, right? But if the main thread is still busy executing the function, onPostExecute will have to wait for it to complete, right? Therefore the function is guaranteed to complete before onPostExecute gets executed?

Comment: @StayFrosty Ya but now the main thread might attached to second Activity which is created after configuration change..